# What does the unix 'pick' command do?

Tags: shell-script

I went through a command called 'pick' in some Unix book, but didn't understand what it does exactly. Below is a sample pick command:

```
pick abc.*
```

Comment: Have you read `man pick`?

Comment: Also, do not Google `man pick` at work.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`pick` command is the one where for each given argument, it asks yes/no and prints the selection to stdout. It accepts a list of choices as input and produces the selected choice as output.
Example to use pick:

```
find -type f | pick | xargs xdg-open
```

This allow you to select a file in the list found by the `find` command using an ncurses(3X) interface and open it with `xdg-open`

Comment: Is it supported in bash shells, because I tried using it in an online bash terminal , and it gave "command not found" error.

Comment: yes it is supported but you must install it `apt-get install pick` (debian)

Comment: Can u explain the command with a simpler query as I am not familiar with xargs command?

Comment: xargs will take the text chosen by the pick command and make an argument to xdg-open from it. another example is `find -name *.txt | pick | xargs gedit`. This will allow you to pick a txt file from the list found by the find command and open it with gedit (xargs will pass it as an argument to gedit)

Comment: so in the above example the 'pick' command will give a prompt for printing the file names on the terminal.. is that correct?

Comment: find will search and show a list of .txt filesfrom your filesystem. pick will allow you to choose one of them in an interactive interface

Comment: thnks.. @Dababi